# Fusion Data API: Is it possible to access the object model data with the Fusion Data API?

Tags: autodesk-forge

Is it possible to access the object model data with the Fusion data API. E.g. SketchCurves, SketchEntity

Answer (score 0):

No, currently [Component](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/fusiondata/v1/reference/objects/component/)/[ComponentVersion](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/fusiondata/v1/reference/objects/componentversion/) is the lowest entity it exposes:
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/fusiondata/v1/reference/objects/

By the way, just deployed a [GraphiQL](https://github.com/graphql/graphiql) based sample that lets you check the documentation and play around with the API to find out more about it: https://fusion-data-explorer.autodesk.io/